# electric charges in electrostatics

Tags: electrostatics

Suppose if a plastic rod is rubbed with fur then plastic rod  get +vely charged and fur get -vely charge after this the +vely charged plastic rod made touch with pith ball then what kind of charge acquired by the pith ball is it +ve or -ve????

Comment: Whenever you touch two objects, you allow charge to flow from one object to another. Now, the direction of charge is such that both the objects finally attain the same charge (and thus, the flow of charge stops). (If its conductor, flow of charge is instantaneous)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Positive  charge because  charge flow from the body at higher potential to the body at lower potential till the charge is same on both body

Comment: If we made touch with fur then what kind of charge acquired by ball